# Re-directed emails have disappeared in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

An employee left our company and so we had his emails come through to my email before we shut his account down. So when people email his address directly, they come through to my email. This has been going for almost a year now, but today I noticed that the folder I had these emails going to has disappeared, and when I searched the email address, all previous emails I had seen could not be found.
Does anybody know why this has happened, and how I can restore it?
Thanks.

Comment: What kind of e-mail account do you have connected to Outlook? Is it Exchange or something else? If Exchange, was the former employee's e-mail address assigned to your mailbox as an alias? Or was something else done to get the messages to you?

Answer (score 1):

If it's an Exchange account or an IMAP account, try logging onto the webmail interface in a browser and check whether you can see the missing folder in the webmail. If you can see the missing folder there, try make a copy of that folder in webmail and see whether the copy of the folder will be synced to Outlook client.

Since a search cannot find the missing emails, if you cannot see the folder in webmail interface, it's more likely that the folder was accidentally and permanently deleted. In this case, try using the 'Recover Deleted Items' feature to recover the permanently deleted items while you use an Exchange account. See [this article](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Recover-deleted-items-in-Outlook-for-Windows-49e81f3c-c8f4-4426-a0b9-c0fd751d48ce) for detailed steps.

If it is an IMAP account, try following [this instructions](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Restore-deleted-messages-when-using-an-IMAP-account-4559a297-4d46-47e7-bfbf-71287b1935ed) to recover the deleted items.

However, if it's a POP3 account, your data are stored in a local PST file. There is no easy way to restore the deleted items unless you have a backup copy of the PST file.